# If I can take a screen capture of a graphical anomaly, can it still be a hardware issue?

Tags: macos, windows-8, graphics-card, imac

I have a strange graphical anomaly going on my iMac right now (green and magenta boxes are appearing sporadically), I'm slowly trying to work through different possibilities but I thought I'd start with the basics:

Can a graphical anomaly that I can screen capture still be a hardware issue?

I know, it seems really obvious.  If it's hardware, it should show up well after the operating system has had it's say.  And since the operating system is (I assume) doing the screen capture, it seems like it shouldn't see the anomaly unless the problem is software in nature.

But, as I've researched this problem I see a lot of people taking their computers in to service people for hardware issues and Apple then resolving said issue.

To further complicate things, I also have Windows 8 installed via bootcamp, and the issues seems to be showing up there as well.

Anyway, it feels like it must be a driver issue, since I assume that's what the two OSes have in common, but...I thought I'd come here for some disambiguation.

In my case, yes, I can screen capture the anomaly (at least in OSX I can), so I assume it's somehow a software (or driver) issue.  But I wanted to double check because the internet is being ambiguous...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can still be a hardware problem.

When a screenshot is taken, it reflects the current video frame as the operating system sees it. A rendering error at the GPU can result in erroneous data being sent to the video memory, which is passed to the system memory and CPU when the screenshot is captured.